# Why to you have to specify the type of the export (let, var, const...) in ES2015?

Tags: javascript, commonjs, node-modules, ecmascript-6

As I'm [reading here](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html), ES2015 allows you to export `var`, `const`, `let`, `function`, `class` and `default`.

```
export var myVar1 = ...;
export let myVar2 = ...;
export const MY_CONST = ...;

export function myFunc() {
    ...
}
export function* myGeneratorFunc() {
    ...
}
export class MyClass {
    ...
}
```

But I don't understand why. In my layman opinion, there should be `named exports` and `default exports`.

The type of what you are exporting doesn't seem to matter. I mean, when you `export default`, do you specify the type? No you don't, and it works. Additionally, what difference can it make to export `var` or `let`? What difference can it make to `export const`? When you import a module it's immutable anyway (AFAIK).

**So, why do you have to specify the type of the export?**

Answer (score 10):

You don't have to specify the type of the export - you have to specify the type of the local binding in your module.

> there should be named exports and default exports.

There are:

```
export {localX as exportedX};
export {localX as default};
```

All those examples you've given are actually shorthands, which both declare a local variable and export it under the same name:

```
var myVar1 = …;
let myVar2 = …;
const MY_CONST = …;
function myFunc() {
    …
}
function* myGeneratorFunc() {
    …
}
class MyClass {
    …
}

export {
    myVar,
    myVar2,
    MY_CONST,
    myFunc,
    myGeneratorFunc,
    myClass
};
```

> What difference can it make to `export const`? When you import a module it's immutable anyway.

That you cannot reassign it *inside* your module. The export doesn't export a value<sup>1</sup>, it exports a binding to your local variable. Imports actually aren't immutable, they are only non-writable.

```
// example.js
export var value; // this one would not work with `const`
export default function(x) {
    value = x;
}
```

```
// main.js
import write, {value} from 'example';
console.log(value); // undefined
write(42);
console.log(value); // 42
```

<sub>1: Default exports are a bit special in that regard. The `export default …` declaration does indeed allow you to directly export the value of an expression (or an anonymous function/function*/class *declaration*), but behind the scenes it actually does create a local variable in your module with the name `*default*`.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Declaring variables, functions or the new const values doesn't have anything to do with exports. The behavior of a var, let or const is different within a module, so you need to indicate what it is. If you export it or not is another thing.

The values are immutable from the outside of a module, but not from the inside (from another exported function for instance).

```
export let mutable = 1;
export const immutable = 2;

export function change() {
    mutable = 11; //works
    immutable = 22; //throws, the value is const
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your export is default, you don't have to specify name or type of what you are exporting, so you can do:

```
export default "whateveryoulike";
```

but named exports are different, you have to specify variable name so that you can import it by this name (type is not important):

```
const x = "whateverelse";
const y = "onemore";
export {x, y as z};
```

Answer (score 1):

you are combining variable declaration with module exports with code like

```
export const x = 10;
```

in the same way that you can't declare a variable with only

```
x = 10;
```

you can't declare a variable and then assign it to a named export with

```
export x = 10;
```

Here is what you can do:

```
const x = 10;
const y = (arg) => arg + 10;
export { x, y };
```

This is essentially just separating the logic of variable declaration and naming module exports