# Generating es6 module exports

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

I'm wanting to programmatically generate the exports for a module, is this possible in es6?

Something along these lines:

```
const ids = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

ids.forEach(id => {
    export const [id.toUpperCase()] = id;
});
```

Comment: possibly related: [What qualifies as being a dynamic export in ES6](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35035457/1048572)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not. Exports and imports are required to be statically analysable in ES6 modules.

Not only is that no-top-level `export` declaration a syntax error, but also your attempt at declaring variables with dynamic names. The bracket notation is reserved for computed *properties* only.

So if you are going to programmatically generate module exports, you'll need to dynamically generate the module source text (as a part of your build process).

Answer (score 0):

You could export an object which has dynamic keys but then you would have to destructure it *after* the import.

```
const ids = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].reduce(...code to reduce to what you want);
export default ids; // { FOO: 'foo', BAR: 'bar', BAZ: 'baz' }
```

```
import ids from './ids'
const { BAR } from ids;
```