# How to make an hybrid package React/React-Native that needs specific imports

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, require

Is that possible to create an hybrid package for React and React-Native that requires specific import, for instance using React-Native I'll have to import AsyncStorage but I'll not need this one for React (using localStorage).

So I was wondering if that's feasible to handle both case using conditional detecting if the app is React-Native or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who can be interested in the future by the implementation of a library that needs specific imports for React and specific imports for React-Native, but can't be mixed, you'll need to create a store for your library, if it can be initialized with React code, you can initialize in your code and create a setter function that'll create a new store to inject the specific dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect if the app is React-Native or not, you will need to use platform specific logic.  According to [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/3c65e62183ce05893be0822da217cb803b121c61), you should be able to check via:

`navigator.product === 'ReactNative'`

Also see here for specific platforms:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html

Comment: I tested it, works well, but I'm still stuck with imports of library in case of its react-native or not.

Comment: Dynamic imports are done via a `require`.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914712/es6-conditional-dynamic-import-statements

Comment: Actually it has been solved by injecting the global variables of the libraries in the context.