# Conditional import of peerDependency in es6

Tags: javascript, import, babeljs, es6-modules, peer-dependencies

I am working on a JavaScript i18n library which localize dates (among other types and objects).

It is currently relying on `moment.js`, which is defined as a peerDependency (localization is one of the features but not the only one, it might not be used)

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "my-i18n-library",
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    // ...
    "clean": "rimraf build",
    "build": "babel src -d build",
    "prepare": "npm run clean && npm run build"
  },
  "peerDependency": {
      "moment": "~2.20.1",
      "date-fns": "~1.29.0"
  },
  // ...
}

// .babelrc
{
  "presets": ["env", "stage-1", "react"]
}
```

Basically something like (a bit more error-proof but I simplified the logic) :

```
import Moment from 'moment.js'
import 'moment/min/locales'

class Localizer {
  localizeDate(value, locale, displayFormat = "L", parseFormat = "LTS") {
    return Moment(date, parseFormat, locale).format(displayFormat);
  }
}
```

Problem is, if `moment.js` is a nice work, it is like a backpack of stones, you would not bring it on a 50 miles trail, especially if you only need to localize one date in a whole application. Bandwidth-wise, it's not worth it IMO (actually in a lot of people opinions as well).

So I am considering switching to lighter libraries such as `date-fns`, but I figured out an option I think is even better :
what if we could let the other choose which library suits him the most?

I was thinking to define different implementations of library-related localizers, and conditionally import them depending of which peerDependency is installed :

```
// /Date/DateFnsLocalizer.js
import { parse } from 'date-fns/parse'
import { format } from 'date-fns/format'

class DateFnsLocalizer {
  localizeDate(value, locale, displayFormat = "L") {
    return format(parse(date), displayFormat, { locale })
  }
}
```

Is that even possible in JavaScript ?

```
// /Localizer.js
if (isModuleDefined('moment.js')) {
  import BaseLocalizer from './Date/MomentLocalizer'
} else if (isModuleDefined('date-fns')) {
  import BaseLocalizer './Date/DateFnsLocalizer'
} else if (isModuleDefined('some-other-lib')) {
  import BaseLocalizer './Date/SomeOtherLibLocalizer'
} else {
  throw new Error('No date library defined! Please install at least one of ["moment.js", "date-fns", "some-other-lib"]')
}

export default class Localizer extends BaseLocalizer
```

I think "import" statements have to be made as first statements in the file. Maybe using `require` instead... (as suggested in [ES6: Conditional & Dynamic Import Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914712/es6-conditional-dynamic-import-statements)) ?  And is it possible to test a module existence without importing it (basically how to code that `isModuleDefined()` method?)

I have seen those ones as well :

[ES6 variable import name in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168433/es6-variable-import-name-in-node-js)

[How can I conditionally import an ES6 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367532/how-can-i-conditionally-import-an-es6-module/46543835)

But as we are currently using `babel` to transpile this library, if this architecture is possible, could it cause compilation troubles in other building tools such as `webpack`, `gulp`, `grunt` etc.?

Comment: Read about dynamic import https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports

Comment: But then we would have to use webpack. I have nothing against but I am not the only one taking that decision. I can always propose it though. But would that be mandatory? And could it cause compilation problems?

Comment: Anyway you can't do this without webpack / rollup for now) You can try zero config software like Parcel, if you don't wanna write your own configuration