# How to import file name in the Axios?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

The import is not working.

```
// 
...

var data1 ="";

...

axios.post(BASE_URL + '/filename')
.then(res => 
{
    data1 = res.data;
    console.log(`This is the data we need :`+data1);
    import data from (`./files/`+ data1);

})
//
```

I imported the data file but i want it to be able to change file name. Now it does not work. Any solutions ?

Comment: Any errors? What exactly does not work?

Comment: Line 52:  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Comment: move import to top

Comment: If i put the import to the top, 

i will get this error : Line 6:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

Which it shows at data1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6: Conditional & Dynamic Import Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914712/es6-conditional-dynamic-import-statements)

Comment: axios.post(BASE_URL + '/filename')

.then(res => 

    {

        data1 = res.data;

        console.log(`This is the data we need :`+data1);

        import(`../files/`+ data1)

        .then((data1) => {console.log(data1.data1);});

    })


The error come out by taking all my files in the console. 

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ''