# Dynamically importing commands. (ES6)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to import classes dynamically when they are required.

The following code works;

```
import TestCommand from "./commands/TestCommand.js"; //At top of the file
```

And in a function;

```
let test = new TestCommand();
console.log(test.getName());
```

And the TestCommand.js;

```
import Command from "./Command.js";

export default class TestCommand extends Command {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.name = "Test";
    } 

    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    execute() {

    }
}
```

However, if I attempt to accomplish the same thing within a function, like so;

```
async function loadCommand(command) {
    let TestCommand = await import("./commands/TestCommand.js");
    let test = new TestCommand();
    console.log(test.getName());
}
```

I get an error; 
(node:14264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: TestCommand is not a constructor

Any suggestions on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: I think you can still use `require` in ES6. Not sure but still have you tried changing `import` to `require`?

Comment: Have you tried console.logging the `TestCommand`? What does it say?

Comment: You probably want `(await import("./commands/TestCommand.js")).default`.

Comment: Maybe this thread about dynamic imports helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914712/es6-conditional-dynamic-import-statements

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. @Felix Kling, that worked perfectly, thank you.