# How to dynamically pass a path to inrequire Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, require

I am trying to set `require()` with a dynamic path `myPath` :

```
let myPath = './myDynamicModule';
require( { myPath } )
```

but I keep getting the error :

```
error: bundling failed: myComponent.js: myComponent.js:Invalid call at line 9: require({
  myPath: myPath
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

**UPDATE**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const ComponentIndex = ({ myModule }) => {
    const myPath = '../modules/' + myModule;

    RevRetComponent = require(revPath).default;

    return <RevRetComponent />;
}

export default ComponentIndex;
```

Comment: `require` accepts a *string* as a parameter, not an object, right?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @certainperformance `myPath` is a place holder for a `String`, that is `let myPath = './myDynamicModule';`

Comment: So, try just passing that string to `require`, instead of wrapping it in an object?

Comment: The string is dynamically defined at runtime. I am receiving it within a function as a parameter. `require( { myPath } )` and `require(myPath)` yield the same errors.

Comment: Sure, so try just passing that string to `require`, instead of wrapping it in an object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6: Conditional & Dynamic Import Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914712/es6-conditional-dynamic-import-statements)

Comment: I just did an update with a more comprehensive module.

Answer (score -3):

Try importing path in this way

```
const path = '../imports/modules/core/startup/client';
import path;
```