# React Local images not loading in the page with Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to create react project form the scratch using webpack. Everything looks fine except the image. Seem images not loading, I can see src="Obeject Object". I used the same file-loader and url-loader on the below webpack but neithrt helps me to fix this issue. I might have missed something in the config file.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var nodeModulesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
var buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'build');
var assetsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/assets');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var config = {

    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    entry: {
        index: ['babel-polyfill', './src/app/index.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: nodeModulesPath
            },

            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                  publicPath: assetsPath,
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                include: [
                    nodeModulesPath,
                    path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
                ],
                use: [
                    // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                    'style-loader',
                    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                    'css-loader',
                    // Compiles Sass to CSS
                    'sass-loader',
                ],
            },
        ],
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/app/index.html'
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',//your ip address
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './',
        hot: true
    },
    target: 'web'
};

module.exports = config;
```

I used image tag like below in react component.

`<img src={require('./../assets/images/logo.png')} />`

Comment: If your application is being served you can directly give the relative path in src.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using your image in your component like:

```
import Image from './image.jpg';

<img src={Image}/>
```

See: [Referencing a local image in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react)

Comment: Yah and  working. Ideally this is not perfect solution if suppose to be used more images ..

Comment: Then what you are looking for is dynamic import (ES7): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914712/es6-conditional-dynamic-import-statements