# Differences between creating a new class to using export const

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, commonjs

Setup:

- BabelJS (es2015, react, stage-1)
- Webpack
- React / redux

New to CommonJS and ES6. I know the difference between an object instance and a static container of methods but I am not sure how they behave when separated to modules. So I wonder what are the differences between returning an instance (is this pattern valid at all?):

```
// StateParser.js

class StateParser {
    constructor() {
     }

     method1() {
        ...
     }

}

export default new StateParser()
```

and exporting const methods:

```
// StateParser.js

let state = {
}

export const method1 = () => { ... }
```

1. Method A: Would there be a new instance every time I import?
2. Method B: Is one of the benefits the ability to use object destructuring:

   ```
   import { method1 } from '../utils/StateParser.js';
   ```

   and then use method1 as if it existed locally?
3. Method A: Is one of the benefits the ability to initialize state in the constructor?

So basically I am not sure when to use which for my utility classes and would appreciate your input.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Would there be a new instance every time I import A?

No, modules are only evaluated once.

> Is one of the benefits of B the ability to use object destructuring and then use method1 as if it existed locally?

Yes, though it's not called "destructuring". They're *named imports* (or *named exports* of the module), and they don't nest and use a different syntax for aliasing.

> Is one of the benefits of A the ability to initialize state in the constructor?

No. You can initialise module state just directly in the module scope as well, you don't need a constructor function for that.

But yes, if you have state in the instances, it's a good idea to use a class which you can *instantiate multiple times*. For that, you need to export the class itself, not an instance, of course.

> Is the `export default new …` pattern valid at all?

No, it's an antipattern for the reasons outlined above. Given the class is used nowhere else, it's quite similar to the [anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38739499/1048572) antipattern. And exporting multiple named exports [is much better](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572) than default-exporting objects anyway.

Comment: Doesn't this work quite differently than anonymous classes in that, as you pointed out, `import A` is only evaluated once? Isn't it technically a singleton instance?

Comment: @thisismydesign Well it doesn't have a name outside the module - you cannot import the class itself - so you could call it anonymous :-) Yes, it is a singleton, which is not only an antipattern in itself (global state), but it is also an antipattern because using `class` syntax for singletons is discouraged.

Comment: I get why it can be considered anonymous but the issues with anonymous classes that you linked don't apply here. You're right that this class definition is an anti-pattern though. However, I think the global state argument highly depends on the context (OP is asking about React), not sure why the [class syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46184368/2771889) is discouraged either.

Comment: @thisismydesign Because [a simple object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1479341/1048572) should be used instead

Comment: That isn't a singleton though, by definition. This is also discussed in detail in that thread. To be fair, this approach of exporting an instance isn't strictly a singleton either.

Answer (score 5):

[We don't recommend](https://github.com/c-hive/guides/blob/bab54b3690885da8abf95004deb34360e63815e8/js/best-practices.md#avoid-exporting-an-evaluation) exporting an evaluation (e.g. `new StateParser()`) for several reasons.

In this case, the module exports the result which is only evaluated once (also mentioned by @Bergi). This is rarely the desired outcome, but if it is, a Singleton pattern should be used instead. Some ES6 module benefits are lost ([tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) and [faster access to imports](https://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#benefit-1%3A-faster-lookup)), it makes imports slower and makes them possible to cause side-effects which should rather happen upon invocation. I also think this is an anti-pattern and the drawbacks can be avoided via exporting a function or class.

It would make more sense to compare `export default StateParser` with exporting const methods.

See also:

- [All exports are static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035304/what-qualifies-as-being-a-dynamic-export-in-es6)
- [ES6 modules are only evaluated once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564901/in-the-import-syntax-of-es6-how-is-a-module-evaluated-exactly)
- [Lost ES6 benefits](https://medium.com/@rauschma/note-that-default-exporting-objects-is-usually-an-anti-pattern-if-you-want-to-export-the-cf674423ac38)