# NodeJS Using decorators with a singleton class does not save the state of the class after init

Tags: node.js, express, decorator

I have a class `MongoQueryResolver` which contains a dictionary:

```
private queries: {[key: string]: (params) => any} = {};
```

This dictionary holds functions by a key, where each function is a query function to MongoDB.

I have created a decorator `MongoQuery` which represents a mongo query function:

```
export function MongoQuery(queryName: string) {
    return function decorator(target, key, func) {
        target.register(queryName, func);
    }
}
```

This decorator calls `MongoQueryResolver#register` in order to register the query in the dictionary so I can use it by the query name.

Example of a MongoQuery function I created:

```
@MongoQuery(QueryType.GET_ALL_ENABLED)
public async getAllEnabled(params) {
    const workersDb = MongoService.getBranch(Branches.WORKERS).db("workers");
    const configCollection = await workersDb.collection('config');

    const criteria: any = {isEnabled: true};

    if (params.proxy) {
        criteria.proxy = params.proxy;
    }

    return await configCollection.find(criteria).toArray();
}
```

and how I use it outside:

```
MyRoutes.get('/get-enabled', async (req, res) => {
    const data = await MongoQueryResolver.resolve(QueryType.GET_ALL_ENABLED, {proxy: req.query.proxy});
    res.json(data);
});
```

**The issue**

When my application inits, I print the dictionary on set:

```
set GET_ALL_ENABLED {
  value: [Function: getAllEnabled],
  writable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true
}
{
  GET_ALL_ENABLED: {
    value: [Function: getAllEnabled],
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true
  }
}
```

But when I get to use the dictionary, its empty ..

I mark the class as a singleton by `export default new MongoQueryResolver()`

Why does it happen? seems like it's a new instance somehow?

```
import MongoQueryResolver from '../../services/mongo/mongo-query-resolver'
```

Comment: Can you show me how you import the `MongoQueryResolver` in the routes file?
Also, it is generally not a good idea to use these `export default new class` as this is considered an antipattern. [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076190/differences-between-creating-a-new-class-to-using-export-const) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739499/anonymous-class-instance-is-it-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Edited from my memory, don't got the source on this pc right now but that's the main idea, I just want to understand why it doesn't work this way

Comment: Can you show how `.register()` and `.resolve()` are implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*After debugging for some time, I figured out the issue.*

There is one reason that this happens, I hope that I am right about this.

Before I start, let me show a small simplified example:

**The decorator**

```
export function MongoQuery(queryName: string) {
    return function decorator(target: any, key: any, func: any) {
        target.register(queryName, func);
    }
}
```

**The Resolver Singleton**

```
class Resolver {
     map: any;

    constructor() {
        this.map = {};
    } 
    
    register(queryName: any, func: any) {
        this.map[queryName] = func;
    }

    resolve(queryName: string) {
       this.map[queryName]();
    }

    @MongoQuery('myQuery')
    public testQuery() {
        console.log("test!");
    }
}
export default new Resolver();
```

**index.ts**

```
Resolver.resolve("myQuery");
```

The issue with this example which is very related to my original example, is that when the decorator runs on the class creation, **it does not run the constructor, nor initializes class variables (if you do `map = {}` at the top)**

Which means that `map` will only be set after the decorator runs.

To solve this, I will have to check in the register function if `this.map` exists, and if not, just set it.

```
register(queryName: any, func: any) {
    this.map = this.map || {};
    this.map[queryName] = func;
}
```

Now I will always have the `map` property set.

Now the only issue remaining is the `resolve` function, when you save the function in the dictionary, it looks like this:

```
 {
  value: [Function: testQuery],
  writable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true
}
```

Which is why I get `is not a function`, so instead of `this.map[queryName]()` I have to run `this.map[queryName].value()` to run the function.

Hope this helps anyone !