# How to use imports when using export default new ClassName();

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules

For example:

File 1:

```
const env = process.env.VARIABLE;
export const config: any = config[env.toLowerCase()];
```

File 2:

```
import { config } from '../file1';
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log(config.someProperty);
  }
}
export default new SomeClass();
```

This doesn't seem to work. config.someProperty is undefined. Any reason why?

Edit per request:

```
import { config } from '../file1';
export class SomeClass {
  private myConfig = config.someProperty;
  constructor() {
    console.log(myConfig);
  }
}
```

Comment: Because `config` is a string. Not sure what properties you expect it to have?

Comment: While your problem is actually unrelated to the `export default new ClassName()`, notice [one should not use that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39076190/1048572).

Comment: Wait, no, `env` is a string (weird name choice), and `config` is coming from a circular definition that throws an exception when evaluating file1.

Comment: So circular reference, ok. I am using the default export new pattern because I want it to be a singleton. I was told that using the pattern of having a private instance, and a static method getInstance() would not guarantee a singleton.

Comment: Yes, `const config = config[env.toLowerCase()];` can't work, on its own already, regardless of any exports/imports. It's in the temporal dead zone. What did you attempt to do there, did you mean to refer to something else?

Comment: Neither does `export default new ClassName` guarantee a single instance of `ClassName`.

Comment: `const config = config[...]` does work though (I am able to import and use it in other files). Just not in any classes that are using `export default new`. Do you happen to have any resources other than the stack overflow answer above that describes how to implement a singleton pattern in node?

Comment: No, it certainly doesn't. Not in any standard-compliant implementation of JavaScript. What do you think the `config` on the right hand side refers to? What does your actual code look like that you say works?

Comment: Regarding your singleton, just don't use a `class` and you'll be good. See the linked answer. Btw, the problem with the `config` is not the export, it's the immediate usage. Try a `console.log(config.someProperty)` in the top-level scope and it won't work either.

Comment: I updated the question with an example of how it is working in my app. I'm using webpack if that makes any difference, but it certainly does work.

Comment: I meant the actual code that declares and initialises `config`. (Yes, webpack might suppress the TDZ error, but it should still throw an exception when accessing `config[env.toLowerCase()]` on `undefined`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to ensure there are no circular dependencies if your environment isn't equipped to handle them. For me, I had a circular dependency between the two classes (not shown in the question), which was resolved by moving the config setup to its own module.