# Export a class or an object instance difference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am confused, or I can say, I have no clue how the exporting actually works.

I have a React app, and I have some protected Routes. On login, I create a `Client` object instance and pass it to child components through Context, and then consume it.

Recently I saw an approach where the example code exported an object instance from a file directly and just imported it in files they wanted to consume it.

```
/** My approach **/
export default Example

/** The Object Instance approach **/
export default new Example()
```

What is the lifecycle of the object instance? Are there any disadvantages with the second approach, because it seems way easier?

Comment: You'll want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076190/differences-between-creating-a-new-class-to-using-export-const/

Answer (score 5):

If you export the class, with

```
export default Example
```

then consumers of the module will be able to instantiate their own instances, and each instance will be able to have its own data. For example

```
// 1.js
import TheClass from './TheClass';
const tc1 = new TheClass();
tc1.foo = 'foo';
```

```
// 2.js
import TheClass from './TheClass';
const tc2 = new TheClass();
tc2.foo = 'bar';
```

Both modules can continue to use `tc1` and `tc2` completely independently, since they're separate instances.

But if the original module exports an instance rather than a class, then all consumers of the module are *forced* to use the same instance:

```
// 1.js
import theInstance from '...';
theInstance.foo = 'foo';
```

```
// 2.js
import theInstance from '...';
// might not be a good idea to do theInstance.foo = 'bar' here
// because that will affect 1.js as well
// and will affect any other modules that imported the instance
```

In short - exporting the class is more reusable than exporting the instance. Sometimes potential reusability is something a script-writer will consider important, and sometimes it isn't. (And sometimes, even if you don't consider it useful initially, you may encounter a situation later that forces you to reconsider.)

And sometimes you want to make sure that there's only one instance ever in a script, in which case

```
export default new Example()
```

is a way to accomplish it.

Comment: So for a React application for example, with multiple imports in multiple files, all of them will consume the same object instance right? Because this approach is very handy for example using a single Driver in the whole application without having to pass it through.

Then the question is will this work the same with lazy load etc.

Comment: It depends on what exactly the class is. If it's a class component, for example, all will consume different instances - `React.createElement` will be called with the class to create instances every time there's a re-render. For things like database interfaces, exporting a single instance used everywhere makes sense. (Or, even better, rather than a class, you could export a plain object in such a case)

Comment: Class makes sense in the beginning, because if it is always exported as an instance, the credentials are not set, so you need the instance initiated in a stale state before setting the creds etc.

Comment: "*you want to make sure that there's only one instance ever in a script*" - then you shouldn't use a `class` though. As anyone can create a `new theInstance.constructor()` …