# are ES2015 modules supposed to pass objects by reference?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

seems to me that ES2015 Modules compiled with babel are simply compiling down to node's [`require`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_object) which passes objects by reference *(as expected for that implementation)*

the question is of the ES2015 spec and going forward in a native ES2015 modules implementation, would that still be the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All objects are [reference values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23556036/1048572) in JavaScript, they are never cloned unless you explicitly tell them to. So yes, that will still be the case.

In fact, ES6 modules are worse than that - `import`ed bindings are not ordinary variables, they are real references to the exported variables (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34381334/1048572) for an example), behaving more like properties of a "module object" than like constants (and that's what babel does compile them to).

Comment: I can tell that's the behavior here so I wasn't sure if its a limitation of transpilers (e.g. babel `const` assignment doesn't throw exception per spec) or in the Spec itself. btw I'm still trying to find the reference to this behavior described in the ES2015 spec?

Comment: @AhmadNassri: It's [all there](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-modules)?