# Can an ES-2015 module be self-aware?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

In a javascript ES-2015 modules, can a module member be aware of what other module members there are?

For example, in a CommonJS module, this is possible:

```
function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
function whoAmI() {
    return Object.keys(module.exports); // ['square','whoAmI']
}
module.exports = {
    square: square,
    whoAmI: whoAmI
};
```

In the equivalent ES-2015 module, how do we write the `whoAmI()` function?

```
export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
export function whoAmI() {
    // ?????
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could import `*` from yourself, and export an `Object.keys` of the result:

```
// myModule.js
import * as exports from './myModule';

export function square(x) { return x * x; }
export let whoAmI = Object.keys(exports);

// consumer.js
import {whoAmI} from `./myModule';
console.log(whoAmI);

> ['square']
```

This will not include `whoAmI`, so to include it:

```
export let whoAmI = Object.keys(exports).concat('whoAmI');
```

Comment: Don't forget that `whoAmI` also needs to return itself. So the output is `['square','whoAmI']`

Comment: By the way, this circular self-dependency is perfectly legal. [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40240659/5743988)

Comment: @torazaburo, why wouldn't `whoAmI` be included in the exports keys? (I agree with @4castle and believe it would.)

Comment: @Constablebrew Well, it's not, because of the way circular imports are resolved.